# WYSIWYG HTML editor for custom cms

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg, dhtml

Am looking for a good and easy to use WYSIWYG HTML editor that i can integrate into a CMS that am currently developing for a client. Am developing the CMS in PHP and is web-based. The editor will have both visual and code view. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Duplicate many times over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wysiwyg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKEditor is a good choice (http://ckeditor.com/)

I've also used TinyMCE.

Both will need to be heavily modified to fit your needs, but the nice thing is both are relatively easy to configure and integrate into just about any system.

Comment: CKEditor absolutely rocks! I wonder why it is not known more widely.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor and TinyMCE are both fine editors.

I'd also add to the list:

- [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) - which is very easy to integrate, but has a few drawbacks -- mostly that the editable area is in a div, not an iframe, so you can end up with some css leakage.
- [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/) - which I've not really used, but it seems to be a fairly robust package.